# Rendering HTML and Javascript in iPython Notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble rendering the output of some javascript in iPython Notebooks. This is what I have currently:

First I reference the external JS library.

```
%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
    highcharts: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.0.1/highcharts'
     }
});
```

Then I'm defining this:

```
widgets.HTML(value='<canvas width=800 height=400 id="chart_highcharts"></canvas>')
js = """
   require(["highcharts"], function() {
  $('#chart_highcharts').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
      x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
      name: 'New York',
      data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
      name: 'Berlin',
      data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
      name: 'London',
      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
  });
});
"""
display(Javascript(js))
```

However nothing actually gets rendered to the canvas.

Comment: Are you sure that the jQuery library and the highcharts' plugin are loaded and available when you try to render?

Comment: Yes, they certainly appear to be.

Comment: Can you do `console.log([window.$,window.jQuery]);` and tell me the output?

Comment: [function, function]

Comment: And what about  `console.log([window.require,window.$.highcharts,window.$.fn.highcharts]);`?

Comment: [function, undefined, function]

Comment: The problem must likely be on `require`. Where is that function defined?

Comment: I think its built into iPython Notebook as it makes use of it itself

Comment: Can you try to run the code directly without the `require()` function?

Comment: Just tried this without the require. Same behaviour exactly. No errors in the console either.

Comment: And what happens when you run `console.log($('#chart_highcharts')[0])`?

Comment: That did not return anything. I think my problem is that I need a `display()` before the `widgets.HTML line`. i.e. display(widgets.HTML(value='<canvas width=800 height=400 id="chart_highcharts"></canvas>')) That seems to render the container for the javascript OK, but I then need to work out how to render the HighCharts data within the `chart_highcharts` id

Comment: My bet will go to the element not being available when you run the Javascript.

Comment: Yes _ think thats whats happening.

Comment: Sadly, this is not my area. My area is only Javascript and PHP. But I think you might want to try to run `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` or `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');` and try to see what it returns, using `console.log`.